# LibreOffice Calc - plot a basic graph

Tags: libreoffice, plot

I can't quite believe I'm having to ask this, but I can't work out how to get LibreOffice Calc to plot a basic graph.

I have this data :-

```
C   R 
11  8.76
22  5.47
44  8.24
53  7.00
36  6.81
36  7.00
34  7.71
23  5.85
32  7.84
45  8.34
26  6.64
```

I just want a straightforward graph of C against R.
C on the X-axis, range 0-60.
R on the Y-axis, range 0-10.

No matter what type of chart I choose from the Insert Chart wizard, I get 11 plots equally spaced along the X axis (there's 11 sets of data). R varies between 5.4 and 8.7 but the XY Scatter gives a much wider range than that. I'm not sure what is being plotted but it's not the values of R.

I've done multiple searches on here, and on Google in general, and have not found anything that helps.  I think I want a *graph*, not a *chart*.

*(Edited - some comments and an answer have been deleted so I've edited the relevant bits into the question to make it clearer)*

Comment: Two identical answers that described exactly what I was already doing.  The actual issue was the the R column was text rather than number. I've accepted the first one on the basis that he has a lot less rep.

Comment: @CarlH Thank you.
I was wondering why someone with 2k reputation in askubuntu can't do that. ;)
The problem was that we were copying data from your text and pasted it as number. Hence we were not able to see your actual problem.
I'll add your comment to my answer hence anybody reading this page in the future could see it easily.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Sometimes copying numbers from another softwares into LibreOffice or using other keyboard layouts rather than English make numbers to be seen as numbers but act as text. Hence you won't get your desired charts or calculations.
So, **first please check your numbers to be numbers rather than text**.

If everything is ok with your data, you can draw your graph/chart using [XY (Scatter) chart](https://help.libreoffice.org/Chart/Chart_Type_XY):

Select your data

[image: Picture of data selected in LibreOffice Calc]

Then from the **Insert** menu select **Chart**.
In the **Chart wizard** window select **XY (Scatter)** as **Chart type** and choose the desired chart look on the top right side of window.
You can also select **Sort by X values** checkbox if you want your data to be sorted by increasing the X values.

[image: Picture of Chart wizard dialog in LibreOffice Calc]

You can change any other desired options in chart wizard and finally press **Finish** to see the final chart.

[image: Picture of sample XY (Scatter) chart in LibreOffice Calc]

Answer (score 0):

The key take away is to chose the XY scatter, not Line, when selecting the Chart Type.